# Sometimes when I want to close an Excel file, I got a PermissionError: [WinError 32]. Why?

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

There are some vectors and I want to calculate the similarities between them. And I want to save the similarity value in an Excel file (.xlsx).
The package I'm using is xlsxwriter.
But sometimes when the "close()" function was called, the error occurs (But not everytime, that means sometimes the program can be executed correctly).

Here is my code:

```
#create a new Excel and a new sheet
sim_order_file = xlsxwriter.Workbook(pre_code + '_' + sim_method + '_' + data_type + '.xlsx')
sim_order_sheet = sim_order_file.add_worksheet()

#write data in the cell
for i in range (len(all_name_sorted)):
    sim_order_sheet.write(i, 0, all_name_sorted[i])

for i in range (len(similarity_value_sorted)):
    sim_order_sheet.write(i, 1, similarity_value_sorted[i])

#close file
sim_order_file.close()
```

And here is the description of error:

```
File "D:\python source\predict_software_ND\program_maliang\get_sim_order_xlsx_SVD.py", line 133, in get_sim_order_xlsx_SVD
sim_order_file.close()


File "E:\anaconda\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\workbook.py", line 299, in close
self._store_workbook()


File "E:\anaconda\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\workbook.py", line 627, in _store_workbook
os.remove(os_filename)

PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 
'C:\\Users\\maliang\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmptwf42i2j'
```

If there is anyone who knows how to solve the problem?

Comment: You probably have it open in MS Excel.

Comment: Actually I didn't open the MS Excel software. But thank you anyway. : )